# Importing FlatBuffers libraries and generated source into Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, import, flatbuffers

We are evaluating [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/index.html) as a potential solution for packing and unpacking various data payloads.  I have built flatc.exe, constructed schemas for our data, and generated Java code from the schemas.  I am now trying to use the generated code.

[This](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_use_java_c-sharp.html) overview states:

> Then you can include both FlatBuffers and the generated code to read or write a FlatBuffer.

And does so as follows in the example:

```
import MyGame.Example.*;
import com.google.flatbuffers.FlatBufferBuilder;
```

1) Should the generated code be imported as a new module/Java Library, dependency, or something else?  How is this done?

2) The import of *com.google.flatbuffers.FlatBufferBuilder* also does not resolve.  Anyone know if this reference has changed?

Appreciate any help you can provide to an Android neophyte on how to import these items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FlatBuffers doesn't come with integrations for any specific IDE's or package managers (which is something we should fix). For now the easiest is to copy the contents of FlatBuffers `java/` folder to where-ever you keep your project's Java code, along with the generated code (in its package directory).

Comment: Just had to update the import paths by hand to match where I put the source  and this worked.  Thanks.